# Can you make VB.NET compilation as strict as C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, compiler-construction

In VB.NET, it is entirely possible to pass an integer as a string parameter to a method without calling `.ToString()` - it's even possible to call `.ToString` without the ()'s. The code will run without a problem, VB will interpret the integer as a string without having been told to.

In C#, these would cause compilation errors - you are required to call `.ToString()` and to call it correctly in that situation before it will compile.

Is there a way to make the VB compilation process check for the same things as the C# compilation process? Would it be best practice in a mixed team to force this check?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several compiler options you can switch on, [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(VS.71).aspx) will do most of what you want i.e. will not allow you to pass an integer for a string.
You set it on the Compile tab for your projects settings, or you can just put `Option Strict On` at the top of a class/module file.

However things like being able to call `o.ToString` instead of `o.ToString()` are part of the language semantics, you can't do anything about that.

If you REALLY want something that compiles just like C#, then you have to use C#.
Sorry :(

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer On
```

in your project settings.

Other than that, not much can be done. VB.NET is a different language and has different kind of restrictions from C#. If you want to make it exactly like C#, why wouldn't you simply switch to C#?

Comment: In my specific case, I joined a team that uses VB.NET. All new projects are created in VB.NET for consistency. But the question came up recently as we were discussing differences, and I was curious.

Comment: @pete: I’m a huge fan of VB, and of consistency. But isn’t one of the big selling points of .NET that different projects, written in different languages (i.e. C# and VB) can work together seamlessly?

Comment: @Konrad: yes, but if your team lead prefers VB, and the only other developer hasn't used C# before... it was explained as "anyone can pick up any project and get to work on it."
Personally, I can flip between the two without a problem, but I can see it would be easier for some people not to have to mentally change gears when they open a different project.

Answer (score 3):

Enabling `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` will make VB **as strict as C#**. Enabling these options in your Visual Studio options is highly recommended (so that they will be enabled for every project). In fact, I recommend to never disable these options, except perhaps on a per-file basis when dealing with COM interop (PIA) where late binding can really make the code more concise.

But as others have said, C# and VB *are* different languages and this is especially evident in their syntax – so omitting the parentheses after a certain method calls will always be possible, just like C# will always require semi-colons at the end of their statements while VB doesn’t allow them.